# Mongoose find() not working with $not query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my find request:

```
Recipe.find({'author.id': {$not: {user}}}
```

Here is the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/index.html

Here is the error:

```
Error: Can't use $not with ObjectId.
```

I want to find all Recipes that are not authored by the current user. The arguments are working fine, so that's not the issue. There must be a way to do this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you want `$ne` 'not equal' rather than `$not` which is a logical operator. see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Comment: I'm thinking you actually mean `.find({ "author.id": { "$ne": user } })` here. So it's `$ne` meaning "not equal" instead of `$not`, which is something else. And it's just `user` and not `{ user }` which actually means `{ "user": user }` and really does not make sense in combination with using "dot notation" already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use **[`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)**

```
Recipe.find({ "author.id": { "$ne": user }});
```